# how to collect one variable in several rows into a new variable in the existing table

Tags: sas

I have a SAS problem how to address the following case:

Initial Data:

```
 gvkey     lender        
000001    citigroup       
000001    abn group       
000001    jpmorgan        
000002    jpmorgan        
000003    morgan stanely  
000003    cibc
```

The result I would like to get:

```
   gvkey     lender          lender_set
  000001    citigroup       citigroup; abn group; jpmorgan
  000001    abn group       citigroup; abn group; jpmorgan
  000001    jpmorgan        citigroup; abn group; jpmorgan
  000002    jpmorgan        jpmorgan
  000003    morgan stanely  morgan stanely; cibc
  000003    cibc            morgan stanely; cibc
```

Could I ask how to use SAS to achieve the result please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you format that desired result set so it is a little more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like below.

```
data have;
input gvkey $    lender & $20.;
 datalines;       
 000001    citigroup       
 000001    abn group       
 000001    jpmorgan        
 000002    jpmorgan        
 000003    morgan stanely  
 000003    cibc     
 ;

proc sort data=have out =have1;
by gvkey;
run;

/* get the concataned value for gvkey_set*/
data have2;
do until(last.gvkey);
set have1;   
by gvkey;
length gvkey_set $100.;
 gvkey_set= catx('; ', gvkey_set,lender);
if last.gvkey then output;
end;
run;

 /* join back concatenated values*/
proc sql;
create table want as 
select a.* ,b.gvkey_set
from have a
inner join 
have2 b
on a.gvkey = b.gvkey;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to generate the same value for the new column for all observations of a group this is a good place to use a double DOW loop.  The first loop will calculate the new column and the second will re-read the data and output the results.

```
data want;
  do until (last.gvkey);
    set have;
    by gvkey ;
    length lender_set $200 ;
    lender_set=catx('; ',lender_set,lender);
  end;
  do until (last.gvkey);
    set have;
    by gvkey ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Make sure that you define LENDER_SET long enough to hold the possible results. Also make sure that it does not already exist on the input dataset.